# Temporarily turn off all notifications on iPhone

Tags: ios, notifications

I don't want my iPhone to vibrate, show me banners, etc., when I toggle the *desired* setting.

I tried *Do Not Disturb* but I don't find it solving the intended purpose.

How can I turn off all notifications temporarily? Is there some feature that's easy-accessible from Control Centre?

I want to watch videos online (in Safari) and not get interrupted by notifications during this.

Comment: Power the iPhone off. Sounds simple, but it is the easiest way to achieve what you want. Works for me in the movie theatre and the funeral I went to last week, where some idiot didn't silence their phone and his ringtone, "I Really Got You" by the Kinks, although funny, was inappropriate.

Comment: It sounds like you did not have Do Not Disturb configured correctly, because what you are asking is exactly what it is designed to do. Be sure that you enable `Settings » Do Not Disturb » Silence » Always` so that DND will be in effect even if you are using the phone. If that does not suffice, please provide some more specifics about what kinds of notifications and alerts you are still seeing with DND enabled.

Comment: @IconDaemon i want to keep using the phone. I watch videos online and don't want to get notifications during that

Comment: @TJLuoma that setting was turned off, i just turned it on and expect it will solve my problem. Why didn't you make that an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I enabled `Settings » Do Not Disturb » Silence » Always` and now my phone has completely silenced notifications.

Answer (score 4):

There is no single settings/toggle that will let you turn off/on all notifications on your iPhone. The way notification are implemented in iOS, you are limited to configure them on a per app basis only.

A couple potential solutions are:

1. Turn on Do Not Disturb. <strike>This will have a side effect of suppressing any regular phone calls.</strike>

   Make sure to set **Allow Calls From** to **Everyone** under Do Not Disturb settings. This will suppress all the notification banners while you are watching videos/playing games in full screen, while keeping the phone function active.

   [image]

   Once you have configured Do Not Disturb as above, you can easily toggle the setting via the Control Center icon.
2. Turn off Internet connectivity by toggling Wi-Fi/Mobile data from Settings app or Control Centre.

The second approach will have a drawback that you won't be able to access the Internet. Also, turning off Internet connectivity won't suppress local notifications.

However, disconnecting from Internet is possibly the best way to temporarily cut-off from the barrage of notification that one receives, while keeping the *basic phone* functionality (calling + SMS) active.

Comment: You said "There is no single settings/toggle that will let you turn off/on all notifications on your iPhone" but doesn't TJ Luoma's comment on the OP work?

Comment: @theonlygusti I understand your point here. However, the original problem statement is a wee bit ambiguous when it comes to handling incoming phone calls. It also didn't contain the intent that you wish to watch videos uninterrupted. I have updated the answer above.